# String checking for contain any symbols except space and tab

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Little but hard for me problem. How I can detect any "visible" symbol in string with true or false as result? For all languages without AZ 09 RegExps.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Check type of first node in elements list. Nodetype is wrong way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all invisible characters, and see if there is anything left:

```
if (s.replace(/\s+/g, '').length > 0) {
  // there are visible characters
}
```

Comment: But `\s` includes newline as well

Comment: @anubhava: Yes. Those are white space characters, thus normally considered invisible.

Comment: Sh.. You are right. How I can forget about this